# "using microsoft.kinect" in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, kinect

I downloaded and installed the Kinect for Windows v2 software. While I'm waiting for the Kinect hardware to arrive, I'm trying to get familiar with the SDK by downloading and compiling open-source Kinect C# projects.

But they won't compile: "using Microsoft.Kinect;" does not pass:

> *warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Kinect, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors.*

The Kinect Configuration Verifier has a green OK for "Verify Kinect Software Installed".

What is wrong? How do I get this namespace to be recognized? Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the reference to Microsoft.Kinect in your project?

Comment: Obviously the project _has_ a reference; it's just not able to _resolve_ it.

Comment: The project has a reference to Microsoft.Kinect. It appears with a yellow warning flag and double clicking it brings the pop-up: "This project cannot be viewed in object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built..."

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use a library you have to add it into the "references" area of VS.

[image]

Add a reference to Microsoft.Research.Kinect.dll there.
(usually located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research KinectSDK)

Comment: The reference exists, but is not resolved. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research KinectSDK does not exist. As I mentioned I installed the software, but do not have the hardware yet. Might this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The referenced kinect assembly Version=1.6.0.0 is from an outdated SDK for the Kinect V1. You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34808) - but samples based on the Kinect V1 will not help you very much to get familiar with Kinect V2 due to fundamental changes in the programming model.

You should look for samples based on the Kinect SDK V2. The SDK already contains some good samples - you will find them in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v2.0_1409\Samples\Managed

.